# Use lubridate to edit year within dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a date frame similar to the following toy data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), date = structure(c(16229, 
    16236, 16243, 16250, 16257, 16600, 16607, 16614, 16621, 16628, 
    16964, 16971, 16978, 16985, 16992), class = "Date"), value = c(0.27, 
    0.37, 0.57, 0.91, 0.2, 0.9, 0.94, 0.66, 0.63, 0.06, 0.21, 0.18, 
    0.69, 0.38, 0.77)), .Names = c("year", "date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Where `value` is some value of interest and `year` and `date` are self-explanatory. If I want to visually compare `value` across years, having the different years in `date` makes the graph not very helpful

```
library(tidyverse)    
ggplot(df, aes(date, value, color = as.factor(year))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I can change the year in `date` using `lubridate` as follows, and this works

```
# This works
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df

year(df2$date) <- 2014

ggplot(df2, aes(date, value, color = as.factor(year))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

But it would be helpful to change this as part of a `dplyr` chain, something along the lines of

```
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(year(date) = 2014)
```

But that code returns an error

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "df3 <- df %>%   mutate(year(date) ="

Is there a way to make this work within a `dplyr` chain, or do I just need to do this edit outside of the chain?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The assignment is just another function call, so you can do:

```
mutate(df, date = `year<-`(date, 2014))
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 15 x 3
>     year       date value
>    <dbl>     <date> <dbl>
>  1  2014 2014-06-08  0.27
>  2  2014 2014-06-15  0.37
>  3  2014 2014-06-22  0.57
>  4  2014 2014-06-29  0.91
>  5  2014 2014-07-06  0.20
>  6  2015 2014-06-14  0.90
>  7  2015 2014-06-21  0.94
>  8  2015 2014-06-28  0.66
>  9  2015 2014-07-05  0.63
> 10  2015 2014-07-12  0.06
> 11  2016 2014-06-12  0.21
> 12  2016 2014-06-19  0.18
> 13  2016 2014-06-26  0.69
> 14  2016 2014-07-03  0.38
> 15  2016 2014-07-10  0.77
> ```

Comment: This is imho much more elegant and should be the accepted solution.

Comment: And it seems the library must be loaded first (i.e. can't use ::).  For example,     
`mutate(df, date = \`lubridate::year<-\`(date, 2014)) `
gives error.

Comment: @MCornejo, the backticks go around the function name excluding the package. `lubridate::\`year<-\``

Answer (score 7):

```
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(date=ymd(format(df$date, "2014-%m-%d")))
df3

# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#     year       date value
#    <dbl>     <date> <dbl>
#  1  2014 2014-06-08  0.27
#  2  2014 2014-06-15  0.37
#  3  2014 2014-06-22  0.57
#  4  2014 2014-06-29  0.91
#  5  2014 2014-07-06  0.20
#  6  2015 2014-06-14  0.90
#  7  2015 2014-06-21  0.94
#  8  2015 2014-06-28  0.66
#  9  2015 2014-07-05  0.63
# 10  2015 2014-07-12  0.06
# 11  2016 2014-06-12  0.21
# 12  2016 2014-06-19  0.18
# 13  2016 2014-06-26  0.69
# 14  2016 2014-07-03  0.38
# 15  2016 2014-07-10  0.77

all.equal(df2, df3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Or use `do`:

```
df4 <- df %>%
  do({year(.$date)<-2014; .})
df4
# same results as df3

all.equal(df2, df4)
# [1] TRUE
```